# ADO.NET linq to MYSQL, orderby not working

Tags: mysql, linq, entity-framework, sql-order-by

I'm trying to sort the query result based on the column that I'm selecting.
But for some reason the result is not sorted. The result is displayed in the same order as it was input to the database. The result doesn't change when I remove the order by line. the "where" clause seems to work properly.

```
var result = (from f in db.firmware
                      where f.firmware_branch_text != ""
                      orderby f.firmware_branch_text!=null, 
                            f.firmware_branch_text

                     select  f.firmware_branch_text                          
                     ).Distinct();
```

The out put is  in this order:

```
2.2.2
2.2.3
2.4.1
2.4.0
3.0.0
2.6.12
2.6.13
2.6.14
2.6.15
2.0.2
```

ANSWER :

Distinct ruins the order, so we need to order after the distinct :

```
var result = (from f in db.firmware
                      where f.firmware_branch_text != ""                          

                     select  f.firmware_branch_text                          
                     ).Distinct().OrderBy(a=>a);
```

Comment: It is perfectly fine to answer your own question, but please put your answer in the box that appears when you click "Answer Your Question". This will make it easier for others to benefit from your answer. Once you do this, people who are helped by your answer could upvote it, which would earn you points. You can also mark your answer as correct by clicking the checkmark next to your answer. You must wait a couple days before you can mark your own answer, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify it:

```
var result = (from f in db.firmware 
                  where f.firmware_branch_text != "" 
                  select  f.firmware_branch_text                           
                 ).Distinct().OrderBy(a=>a);
```